# Adding punctuation in nested templates

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to add elements with a comma and a space in `<album>` if it is not the last `<album>` within a parent `<recording>`.

I have a similar template for `<recording>`s, which works as expected. However, I cannot get the second template for the `<album>` punctuation to work correctly.

I believe it has something do to with the first template existing...

**Input XML**

```
<sample>
<collection>
    <recording>
        <artist>Radiohead</artist>
        <album>OK Computer</album>
    </recording>
    <recording>
        <artist>Tori Amos</artist>
        <album>Boys For Pele</album>
        <album>To Venus And Back</album>
    </recording>
</collection>
```

**Sample XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="collection">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="recording">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:element name="x">, </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="recording">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="album">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <comma>, </comma>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**But my output is**

```
<sample>
<collection>
    <recording>
        <artist>Radiohead</artist>
        <album>OK Computer</album>
    </recording><x>, </x>
    <recording>
        <artist>Tori Amos</artist>
        <album>Boys For Pele</album>
        <album>To Venus And Back</album>
    </recording>
</collection>
```

**Instead of what I want** (note the `<x>`, after the first `<album>` in the second `<recording>`)

```
<sample>
    <collection>
        <recording>
            <artist>Radiohead</artist>
            <album>OK Computer</album>
        </recording><x>, </x>
        <recording>
            <artist>Tori Amos</artist>
            <album>Boys For Pele</album><x>, </x>
            <album>To Venus And Back</album>
        </recording>
    </collection>
</sample>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second (matches *collection*) template to

```
<xsl:template match="collection">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="recording">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:element name="x">, </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and modify your *recording* template to

```
<xsl:template match="recording">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="(node() | @*) except album"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="album">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <x>, </x>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

removing the `xsl:copy` element and replacing it with an `xsl:apply-templates` element and moving the call to the other recording children into the *recording* template.

As it stands originally, you are looping over the recording elements and applying a template to the content nodes.  Thus you are never allowing the *recording* template to match anything.  By applying the template to the current context node, we are working with the *recording* node itself instead of its contents allowing the *recording* template to match.

Additionally, in your *recording* template, you are adding a *comma* element instead of an *x* element.  I have changed these to *x* elements above, as that is what you seem to have wanted.

---

Additionally, your first `xsl:for-each` is not even needed.  If we move the position test from the *collection* template to the *recording* template we can simplify the *collection* template to avoid the `xsl:for-each`:

```
<xsl:template match="collection">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="recording"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="recording">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="(node() | @*) except album"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="album">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <x>, </x>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:element name="x">, </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>       
</xsl:template>
```

---

We could even do the same thing with the albums, eliminating both `xsl:for-each` elements

```
<xsl:template match="collection">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="recording"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="recording">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="(node() | @*) except album"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="album"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:element name="x">, </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>       
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="album">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <x>, </x>
    </xsl:if>       
</xsl:template>
```

---

All of the above will copy the text nodes between elements which are entirely whitespace, which may not be desirable.  Adding the following to the top of the stylesheet will prevent that:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

---

All examples in this post were tested using the OP's original example with the additional `xsl:strip-space` element and `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>` using **Saxon-HE 9.7.0.2J** and produced results equivalent to the OP's desired output up to indenting (the *x* elements occurred on their own lines).

Comment: Thank you very much for the concise explanation. It was very helpful and produced my desired result. I knew there was some sort of looping that I needed to get around with these two templates.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a template that matches either `recording` or `album` and if it's not the first of its kind, output the `<x>, </x>`.

**XML Input**

```
<sample>
    <collection>
        <recording>
            <artist>Radiohead</artist>
            <album>OK Computer</album>
        </recording>
        <recording>
            <artist>Tori Amos</artist>
            <album>Boys For Pele</album>
            <album>To Venus And Back</album>
        </recording>
    </collection>
</sample>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="recording|album">
    <xsl:variable name="count">
      <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="$count > 1"><x>, </x></xsl:if>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<sample>
   <collection>
      <recording>
         <artist>Radiohead</artist>
         <album>OK Computer</album>
      </recording>
      <x>, </x>
      <recording>
         <artist>Tori Amos</artist>
         <album>Boys For Pele</album>
         <x>, </x>
         <album>To Venus And Back</album>
      </recording>
   </collection>
</sample>
```